# BeautifulSoup: Indian language changing to unicode when printing out onto terminal using findAll. function

Tags: python, unicode, terminal, beautifulsoup

I wanted to scrap popular Indian (Using Scrapy) sites in native languages for creating a dictionary of the most frequently used words in the Indian Language (Malayalam), after parsing the response using BeautifulSoup from a website and printing out onto the terminal using,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

I get this output on the terminal,

...

```
<div class="articleBody common_text" id="content2044131">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<p>വൈറസുകള്‍ എന്നൊരു സാധനമേ ഇല്ല, അത് ഭൂലോക തട്ടിപ്പാണ്. കേരളത്തിലെ പ്രശസ്തനെന്ന് അറിയപ്പെടുന്ന വൈദ്യരുടെ പ്രസ്താവന ആണിത്. മാത്രമല്ല വൈദ്യര്‍ കേരളത്തിലെ ഏറ്റവും വലിയ പീഡിയാട്രീഷനായ ഏതോ ഡോ. പിഷാരടിയോടു ചോദിച്ച് <a href="https://www.facebook.com/181790438911986/videos/313673832390312/"><strong>ഇക്കാര്യം ഉറപ്പുവരുത്തുക കൂടി ചെയ്തു</strong></a>. വൈദ്യരെയും പിഷാരടിയെയും പറഞ്ഞിട്ട് കാര്യമില്ല, കാരണം വൈറസുകളെ കാണാന്‍ സാധിക്കില്ലല്ലോ. പിന്നെ അവ ഉണ്ടെന്ന് എങ്ങനെ  വിശ്വസിക്കും?  </p>
<p>ഈ ലേഖനം എഴുതാന്‍ കാരണം വൈദ്യരും പിഷാരടിയും മാത്രമല്ല, ഈ അടുത്ത് ഒരാള്‍ ഇതിലും ഞെട്ടിക്കുന്ന ഒരു വാദം പറഞ്ഞു. ഇലക്ട്രോണ്‍, പ്രോട്ടോണ്‍ തുടങ്ങിയ സംഗതികളെല്ലാം ശാസ്ത്രത്തിന്റെ ഭാവന ആണത്രെ. ഇലക്ട്രോണ്‍ വിരുദ്ധരും വൈറസ് വിരുദ്ധരും ചോദിക്കുന്നത് 'കണ്ടിട്ടുണ്ടോ' എന്നാണ്. ഉത്തരം ഇല്ല എന്നുതന്നെ. പക്ഷെ കണ്ടാല്‍ മാത്രമേ വിശ്വസിക്കാന്‍ കഴിയുകയുള്ളോ? കാണാതെ എങ്ങനെ വിശ്വസിക്കും? ഇതാണ് ഈ ലേഖനത്തില്‍ പറയാന്‍ ഉദ്ദേശിക്കുന്നത്. </p>
```

...

Fair enough, but after parsing the section I want using

```
    div = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "articleBody common_text"})
    print(div)
```

I get this on the terminal,

```
<div class="articleBody common_text" id="content2044131">\n<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">\n<p>\u0d35\u0d48\u0d31\u0d38\u0d41\u0d15\u0d33\u0d4d\u200d \u0d0e\u0d28\u0d4d\u0d28\u0d4a\u0d30\u0d41 \u0d38\u0d3e\u0d27\u0d28\u0d2e\u0d47 \u0d07\u0d32\u0d4d\u0d32, \u0d05\u0d24\u0d4d \u0d2d\u0d42\u0d32\u0d4b\u0d15 \u0d24\u0d1f\u0d4d\u0d1f\u0d3f\u0d2a\u0d4d\u0d2a\u0d3e\u0d23\u0d4d. \u0d15\u0d47\u0d30\u0d33\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d3f\u0d32\u0d46 \u0d2a\u0d4d\u0d30\u0d36\u0d38\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d28\u0d46\u0d28\u0d4d\u0d28\u0d4d 
\u0d05\u0d31\u0d3f\u0d2f\u0d2a\u0d4d\u0d2a\u0d46\u0d1f\u0d41\u0d28\u0d4d\u0d28 \u0d35\u0d48\u0d26\u0d4d\u0d2f\u0d30\u0d41\u0d1f\u0d46 \u0d2a\u0d4d\u0d30\u0d38\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d3e\u0d35\u0d28 \u0d06\u0d23\u0d3f\u0d24\u0d4d. \u0d2e\u0d3e\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d30\u0d2e\u0d32\u0d4d\u0d32 \u0d35\u0d48\u0d26\u0d4d\u0d2f\u0d30\u0d4d\u200d \u0d15\u0d47\u0d30\u0d33\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24
```

Why did it suddenly get converted into raw unicode? Is there a proper way to parse it. And just for the info what I intend on doing after is scrap individual words from the articles and store it into a json file with the corresponding word and the number of times it occurred, somewhat like this

```
{
  "സാധനമേ": 67,
  "കേരളത്തിലെ": 69,
  "ഒരാള്‍": 50,
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: You can access the text of the div using div.text and split based on ' ' to get word list which then can be used to create a count json

Comment: Yeah, but to get that div Ill have to use findAll, it gets converted into unicode when I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had something to do with encoding. By using `utf-8` encoding on a bs4 object, I was able to get the required output.

Changing,

```
div = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "articleBody common_text"})
print(div)
```

To,

```
div = soup.select(".articleBody")[0]
print(div.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Solved the problem.